# Difference between rehman and al rehman

Tags: arabic, arabic-translation

What is the difference between  Rehman and Al Rehman?

Or they both exactly same

Comment: This looks like a question on Arabic language which is not the topic of the site.

Answer (score 1):

In Arabic, the article "Al-" or as in Arabic ال, indicates that the name which comes right after it is "known" and "definite". Close to "the" in English or "Le/La/Les" in French.

The word Rehman, itself, is an adjective, meaning "Gracious" , "Kind" , "Compassionate". But in Islamic context, Al-rehman (الرحمن) means Allah, as in بسم الله الرحمن الرحیم. Or as in the holy Quran:(سورة الرحمن/ آیات ۱-۲)
*

> (۲)الرَّحْمَنُ (۱) عَلَّمَ الْقُرْآنَ

- which means, 
  The Compassionate [Allah], taught the Quran.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will answer your question.

> Rahman (Arabic: رحمن‎, Raḥmān) is an Arabic male name meaning
>   Gracious. With nisba (Arabic onomastic), the name becomes Rahmani,
>   means "descendant of the gracious one" and is used as a surname. In
>   Islam, Ar-Rahman (The Most Gracious) is one of the Names of God.